# How to draw an arc using YUI3 grahics module?

Tags: javascript, svg, vector-graphics, yui3

I've checked the docs for YUI3 graphics module but can't seem to find any method to draw a arc ? There are functions for bezier curves but none for arc. Its strange considering that arc is very well supported by SVG path, but can't be drawn with YUI ?

Should I just quit YUI3 graphics and use RaphaelJS - it seems to have everything.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got your answer here from official yui team:

http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=33410

> The Graphics Path shape does not currently support an arc method.
>   Please file a ticket and I will add one.

So either wait for them to implement it or use another library.

The good thing about yui and their team - they are quite agile and turnaround time for changes is pretty quick.

I looked a bit more in the graphics module and I see this:

http://yuiblog.com/sandbox/yui/3.3.0pr3/api/graphics-svg.js.html

```
drawWedge: function(x, y, startAngle, arc, radius, yRadius)
```

there is also

```
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/graphics_js_CanvasPieSlice.js.html#l1
```

try those to see if they work.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like they won't if it before 3.6 :(